# Calculating points on a circle for 3D rotation

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, geometry

So I decided to play around with some basic 3D. I wanted to start this by having a cube one the screen and be able to rotate this cube in all directions. I'm starting by rotating it on the `x plane`. **The issue I'm having is that the two points at the top and bottom of the cube (being the points near the 0-180º mark) are moving faster than all of the rest.** More explanation after.

```
public Integer[] circleMath(int rotation, int x_rot, Double main_x, Double main_z){
    Double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(100, 2) * 2); // Calculating diametre of circle. Ends up around 141

    int tx_rot = x_rot + rotation; // Each point has an offset in rotation from main cube, these are at intervals of 90ª
    boolean over = false; // For deciding if to use positive or negative result from sqr
    if (tx_rot >= 360){ tx_rot -= 360; } // This occurs when rotation offset is added
    if (tx_rot > 180){ tx_rot = 360 - tx_rot; over = true; } // Has gone past 180 degrees, use neg result from sqr

    Double z = (main_z - (tx_rot * d / 180) + (d/2)); // Explained below (1)
    Double x = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(d / 2, 2) - Math.pow(z - main_z, 2))); // Uses x^2 + y^2 == r^2
    if (over){ x *= -1; } // Neg result

    // Returning values
    Integer ret[] = new Integer[2];
    ret[0] = (int) Math.round((x + main_x));
    ret[1] = (int) Math.round(z);
    return ret;

}
```

This is the function I'm using to calculate the points at various areas. The basic logic follows.

1. Calculate `z` based off `x_rot` (the rotation of the object)
2. Use this as a `y` value to find `x (x^2 + y^2 = r^2)`

Calculating the `z` consists of dividing the diameter of the circle into 180 (180º), the rest is self-explanatory.

Here are some results I recorded.

```
tx_rot: 175 x: -23.240556292613196 z: -66.78230711206282
tx_rot: 176 x: -20.846292265881893 z: -67.56798131338121
tx_rot: 177 x: -18.104634152000347 z: -68.3536555146996
tx_rot: 178 x: -14.824071182362571 z: -69.13932971601798
tx_rot: 179 x: -10.511604404680254 z: -69.92500391733637
tx_rot: 180 x: 0.0 z: -70.71067811865476
```

You can see that the `z` is constant in decreasing by `~0.7` but the `x` seems to be `exponential-ish`. When the `tx_rot` is `180`, `z` reaches the radius which is perfect and the `x` is expected to bottom out.

**Any ideas as to why the x is so inconsistent would be greatly appreciated.**

Let me know if you need anymore information, I've got no clue what's wrong

What it looks like at 0º rotation :)
[image]